# Why does an HTML 5 video tag not work for using a YouTube video as source?

Tags: html, youtube, html5-video

Using Chrome, if I look into a YouTube's page, such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5CjKEFb-sM then I will see that the following HTML5 is responsible for showing the video:

```
<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" 
    style="width: 640px; height: 360px; left: 0px; top: 0px; 
           transform: none;" 
    src="blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/71c0fdee-822a-4b58-9ed5-fef443f2e7fd">
</video>
```

to verify, I set the CSS to `display: none` and the video disappeared, so that should verify that this is the code for showing the video.  Now if I make a file on my hard drive as `try.html`:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" 
    style="width: 640px; height: 360px; left: 0px; top: 0px; 
           transform: none;" 
    src="blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/71c0fdee-822a-4b58-9ed5-fef443f2e7fd">
</video>
```

That is, just the `DOCTYPE` together with that `<video>` tag, and then open this `try.html` file using Chrome, I don't see anything.

I understand that the suggested embedding method as suggested by YouTube is by an `iframe`, but I wonder why `try.html` doesn't work, and how to make it work?  Related is, what is the `blob:https%3A` part... if I use the developer tool to "Open Link in a New Tab", then nothing will show and how to make it show? (both URLs blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/a5837a85-ca81-48dc-99b8-48e69a9b4f64 and https://www.youtube.com/a5837a85-ca81-48dc-99b8-48e69a9b4f64 do not work).

Comment: Check this : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp

Comment: I think the question is not about "what can embed a video", but more about HTML5 and why it doesn't work and is there a way to open the video URL in a new tab

Comment: I'm pretty sure Youtube blocks video content unless it's requested by youtube.com.

Comment: there are some YouTube video downloader add-on for Firefox and somehow they can download YouTube videos... so are you saying they fake the `HTTP_REFERER`?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/2c375ed8-2ad9-491b-aae9-9a6d6fefacc6">

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```